# php - Unable to install SonataUserBundle in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I can't install sonata-project/user-bundle with symfony. Composer gives me such error message:

> app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src
>                                                                                [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "sonata:easy-extends" namespace.

Did you mean one of these?

> sonata:user
>         sonata:admin
>         sonata:block
>         sonata:core
>         sonata

Comment: Have you include the bundle in your appKernel ? https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/installation.html

Comment: I means that you haven't registered [SonataEasyExtendsBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataEasyExtendsBundle) on your `AppKernel.php` under `registerBundles` function.

Comment: You are right need to add SonataEasyExtendsBundle bundle.